# Return part of string

Tags: php

I have an array with strings like:

```
209@ext-local : SIP/209 State:Idle Watchers 2
208@ext-local : SIP/208 State:Unavailable Watchers 1
```

How can I echo the state for example Idle or Unavailable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strpos will search the string to see if it is contains the characters in that exact order.
strpos will not always work if the word idle or unavailable has the possibility to show up in any other way in the string.

You can use the php explode and parse the sting into an array of strings.

exp.

```
$string = "209@ext-local : SIP/209 State:Idle Watchers 2";
$string = explode(':', $string);
```

will give you ['209@ext-local ',' SIP/209 State','Idle Watchers 2'].  Then if you explode the 3rd entry my ' ' you would get your answer.

```
$answer = explide(' ', $string[2]);
echo $answer[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex it will match any string containing letters and numbers.

```
$string = '209@ext-local : SIP/209 State:Idle Watchers 2';
preg_match("/State\:([A-Za-z0-9]+)/", $string, $results);

echo $results[1]; // Idle
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick (and dirty) way.  Assuming your array contains the full elements you listed above, the array element values do NOT contain 'idle' or 'unavailable' in any other capacity other than what you listed, and you just want to echo out the value and "is idle" or "is unavailable":

```
//$a being your array containing the values you listed above
foreach ($a as $status) {
    if (strpos($status, "Idle") == true)
        echo $status . " is idle";
    elseif (strpos($status, "Unavailable") == true)
        echo "$status" . " is unavailable";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your strings are all the same format, you can try splitting the string down using `explode()`, which returns an array of string, separated by a provided delimiter, like

```
foreach ($yourStrings as $s) {
    $colonSplit = explode(":", $stringToSplit);
    $nextStringToSplit = $colonSplit[2];
    $spaceSplit = explode(" ", $nextStringToSplit);
    $status = $spaceSplit[0];

    echo $status;
}
```

May not be elegant but it should work.